# Creating a report listing contacts grouped by an employer-group

Tags: civireport

How can I create a report that lists contacts & their employer, but groups them by a employer group?

I.e.

## Sports

- John - Adidas
- Jane - Nike

## Food

- Jim - Kraft
- Jack - Nestle

And so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Drupal and are familiar with or willing to explore Views then I would expect a grouped display like this based on a 'tag' or whatever characteristic 'food' is would be do-able. Happy to explain more if that is a solution you can use.